# Socket IO times out after some time of innactivity, doesn't work, why?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to socket IO and all, I've been working with it for about the last month, but I have noticed over the time that if I let my website sit and not do anything for a small amount of time, (Im not sure how much), but it seems to timeout, and the events aren't called unless I reload the page. There must be a way to fix this?

my server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(4000);

var users = {};

io.disable('heartbeats');

////////////////USER CONNECTED

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.emit('connected');
    socket.on('session', function (session) {

    ///all my other functions here

    });
});
```

then included on my page is:

```
<script>var socket = io.connect("http://<?php print $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>", 
        {port: 4000, 'reconnect': true,'reconnection delay': 1500});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ws/data/data.js"></script>
```

data.js is where all of my socket io functions are for the user end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line:

```
io.disable('heartbeats');
```

See [Configuring Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO).